# perl search & replace script for all files in a directory

Tags: perl, replace

I have a directory with nearly 1,200 files. I need to successively go through each file in a perl script to search and replace any occurrences of 66 strings. So, for each file I need to run all 66 s&r's. **My replace string is in Thai, so I cannot use the shell. It must be a .pl file or similar so that I can use** `use::utf8`. I am just not familiar with how to open all files in a directory one by one to perform actions on them. Here is a sample of my s&r:

```
s/psa0*(\d+)/เพลงสดุดี\1/g;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What OS do you have? If some kind of *nix then it's simpler to use something like `for f in *; do perl_script -i "$f"; done`

Comment: Windows with Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`opendir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#opendir)/[`readdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readdir)/[`closedir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#closedir) for functions that can iterate through all the filenames in a directory (much like you would use `open`/`readline`/`close` to iterate through all the lines in a file).

Also see the [`glob`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#glob) function, which returns a list of filenames that match some pattern.

Comment: The glob function was the key. I will post what I actually did in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Glob qw( bsd_glob );

@ARGV = map bsd_glob($_), @ARGV;

while (<>) {    
   s/psa0*(?=\d)/เพลงสดุดี/g;
   print;
}
```

```
perl -i.bak script.pl *
```

I used [File::Glob](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aGlob)'s `bsd_glob` since `glob` won't handle spaces "correctly". They are actually the same function, but the function behaves differently based on how it's called.

---

By the way, using `\1` in the replacement expression (i.e. outside a regular expression) makes no sense. `\1` is a regex pattern that means "match what the first capture captured". So

```
s/psa0*(\d+)/เพลงสดุดี\1/g;
```

should be

```
s/psa0*(\d+)/เพลงสดุดี$1/g;
```

The following is a faster alternative:

```
s/psa0*(?=\d)/เพลงสดุดี/g;
```

Comment: thanks. actually in the final script I changed it to `$1` because perl complained. either way it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone could use it in the future. This is what I actually did.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use utf8;

my @files = glob ("*.html");

foreach $a (@files) {
   open IN, "$a" or die $!;
   open OUT, ">$a-" or die $!;
   binmode(IN, ":utf8");
   binmode(OUT, ":utf8");
   select (OUT);
   foreach (<IN>) {
      s/gen0*(\d+)/ปฐมกาล $1/;
      s/exo0*(\d+)/อพยพ $1/;
      s/lev0*(\d+)/เลวีนิติ $1/;
      s/num0*(\d+)/กันดารวิถี $1/;
      ...etc...
      print "$_";
   }
   close IN;
   close OUT;
};
```